# Inheritance and dependency injection with Roboguice and RxJava

Tags: java, inheritance, rx-java, roboguice

I have one base class and 2 derived classes. I will attempt to explain with a very simplified version:

```
public class AllIntegers{
    List<Integer> myList;
    BehaviorSubjec<Integer> behaviorSubject;
    @Inject
    public AllIntegers(List<Integers> allIntegers) {
       behaviorSubject = BehaviorSubject.create();
       //some logic
    }
    public BehaviorSubject<Integer> getAllIntegersBSAsObservable() {
      return this.behaviorSubject.asObservable();
    }
}


public class OddIntegers extends AllIntegers {
    List<Integer> myList;

    @Inject
    public OddIntegers(... some dependencies...) {
       /* ... some logic ... */
       //Getting observable from parent
       getAllIntegersBSAsObservable.subscribe(new Subscriber(...));
    }
}

public class EventIntegers extends AllIntegers {
    List<Integer> myList;

    @Inject
    public EventIntegers(... some dependencies...) {
       /* ... some logic ... */
       //Getting observable from parent
       getAllIntegersBSAsObservable.subscribe(new Subscriber(...));
    }
}
```

My Roboguice module file looks like this:

```
bind(IAllIntegers.class).to(AllIntegers.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
bind(IOddIntegers.class).to(OddIntegers.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
bind(IEventIntegers.class).to(EventIntegers.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
```

Again, I OVER simplified here to make it easier to write and understand.

The problem is that Roboguice creates an instance of AllIntegers.class as it should. I have to however add an empty constructor to the AllIntegers.class for the compiler to not complain, this of course causes OddIntegers and EventIntegers to EACH get their OWN instance of AllIntegers, so both children get different instances of the observable while the singleton base class also gets its own (this is the one I actually want), so when I fire onNext on the behavior subject, the children do not react because the behavior subject is different.

Should I be using composition instead of inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Roboguice is the problem, this is standard behaviour. You're calling `getAllIntegersBSAsObservable`, an instance method, wich returns `this.behaviorSubject.asObservable();` an instance field. Even though all instances are singletons, they are still separate instances, so they each have their own instance of `behaviorSubject`.

---

A possible fix is to make `behaviorSubject` a `static` field.

Comment: You are correct, it is not a Roboguice problem, it is not in fact a problem with anything other than my design. The combination of singletons, dependency injection and inheritance that I coded introduced this issue. I like your solution of marking the behaviorSubject a static field, although it still seems like a band aid solution for the problem I introduced. I think I have to get some coffee and just re-factor it